# Require adjust the cell height of parent TableView contains a Child TableView with expandable header written in Swift 5.7

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nested

The requirements are:

1. The parent table will show the Blog Post and may contain multiline label
2. Each blog post may contain reader comments, which are shown in the child tableview row with multiline label. The child tableview will have expand/ collapsible header to reduce the default height of parent table view.
3. While expand the child tableview, the cell height of parent table should be adjusted to accommodate the expanded rows of child table view.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You almost **certainly** want to use multiple sections in a single table view, rather than embedded tableViews in cells.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the height of the Tableview dynamically during expand/collapse. Use automatic dimensioning for cell heights in both the parent and child table views by setting the rowHeight property to `UITableView.automaticDimension.` Set the Line of the labels as 0 in Storyboard First and then Implement the necessary delegate methods `(tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:))` to provide estimated and actual heights for the parent cells based on their expanded/collapsed state and content.